# How to comma separate the values of an array for display

Tags: php, arrays, list, split

I have searched the PHP.net site and originally thought of some use for the `list()` function but doesn't seem to accomplish the goal:

I have an unknown number of values stored in a single array

`$array1 = array(1,2,3,4,5);`

or

`$array1 = array(1,2,3);`

I want to be able to echo (or `print_r`) the values contained within an array to screen and separated only by commas and spacing.

For example:

the 'idea' is to have echo `$array1` to display:

1,2,3

from the second example above.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

```
echo implode(", ", $array);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use PHP's [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function for this purpose as follows:

```
$string = implode(',', array(1,2,3,4,5));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `list()` function if you know there are only 3 values.

```
$array = array('Life', 'living', 'Health');
list($life, $living, $health) = $array;

echo $life;
echo $living;
echo $health;
```

Note - you can make use of `implode` function as well.